# Avoid hard-coding controller and action names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.NET MVC seems to be encouraging me to use hard-coded strings to refer to controllers and actions.

For example, in a controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

or, in a view:

```
Html.RenderPartial("Index", "Home");
```

I don't want hard-coded strings all over my code. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: There is no problem with this IMHO. At some point you have to tell the code to point to a specific class or function.

Comment: @Badger the problem is what if you rename your actions/controllers. You then have to somehow find all the hard-coded strings to update them and you can't rely on the compiler to tell you that you've missed something.

Comment: ReSharper can make this non-problem

Comment: @Dolbz that's why you write unite tests :)

Comment: @frennky I'd rather not write unit tests for something that the compiler can reasonably find for me with zero effort ;)

Comment: @kristian - if you like my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @frennky how do I write unite tests, they sound cooler and more powerful than integration tests? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to use strongly typed redirects. I made a static helper class called RedirectionHelper that has the following method:

```
public static string GetUrl<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action, RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values = null) where T : Controller
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues = ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);

    if (values != null)
        foreach (var value in values)
            routeValues.Add(value.Key, value.Value);

    return urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeValues);
}
```

The only caveat is that you will have to use the Microsoft.Web.Mvc futures library available out on Nuget.

Now, for your controller, create a base controller that all controllers inherit from that has this method:

```
protected RedirectResult RedirectToAction<T>(Expression<Action<T>> action, RouteValueDictionary values = null) where T : Controller
{
    return new RedirectResult(RedirectionHelper.GetUrl(action, Request.RequestContext, values));
}
```

Now, in your action, all you have to do is say:

```
return RedirectToAction<Controller>(x => x.Index());
```

Likewise, you can write a html extension method that takes in the same parameters and builds your anchor tag.

Like you said above that you wanted, when you change Controller or Action names, your project will break at compile time and show you where the breaks occur. However, this will only occur in the controllers, seeing as how the views don't compile.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice :) I posted same solution a few seconds later

Comment: nice - much better than messing about with t4 templates - which suck if i'm honest

Comment: Note: For this to work the ExpressionHelper must be `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper`, **not** `System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper`.

Comment: Using this approach, how to redirect to shared views?

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal you _can't_ redirect to shared view. You _can_ redirect to another controller action, that returns a shared view (this is the MVC principle).

Answer (score 5):

Look at [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) this generates classes so you can have strongly typed actions and controller names. As it's still just a mapping to a string, refactoring won't cause the names in your views to update if you change a controller name for example.

After regenerating you will get compilation errors due to the names disappearing from your generated classes though so it's still useful in refactoring and catches problems that you can miss using hard-coded strings.

Answer (score 4):

try T4MVC: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if somebody already added an extension method to one of the ASP.NET MVC related projects but here's a piece of code that you can use to create your own extension method:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) where TController : Controller
    {
        RouteValueDictionary rv = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);

        return RedirectToAction((string)rv["Action"], (string)rv["Controller"], routeValues ?? new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction<DashboardController>(x => x.Index(), null);
    }
```

There's no parameters merging logic, so you'll have to add it by your own.

UPDATE: @mccow002 added a similar solution a few seconds before me, so I think his solution should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but when I was looking for an answer for ASP.NET 5 this theme first appeared.
There is no need to hardcode anymore, just use *nameof*

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult List()
{
   ...
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add()
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
}
```

Comment: This won't work if someone overrides the action name via the ActionName attribute e.g. `[ActionName("NewActionName")]`

Comment: @DavidSpence
Yeah, also it won't work with controllers as is, you need to implement extension method that will cut off "Controller" suffix. However that's something.